# Dealing with groups on Bison

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to write a parser using flex and bison but I'm confused on how it works. I'm trying to take a text file formatted in the following way:

```
Version Header Version 1.00 <--- File always starts with a header
Key                     : Value <--- Each section includes these but these after the version header are in the "Root" section
==Section Name <--- A section
$Key                    : Value <--- These are properties
Key                     : Value <--- Same thing as in the "Root" section
```

Sample Format:

```
NasuTek Licensing Version 1.00
Vendor                  : NASUTEKENTERPRISES
Notice                  : NasuTek Enterprises
License Group           : NasuTek Asheila
License Name            : NasuTek Asheila
Vendor Notice           : NasuTek Asheila Internal Build License
Serial                  : ASHEL-87267-4987-3737-37821:32742
Start Date              : Wed July 04 00:00:00 2012
End Date                : Sat July 20 00:00:00 2013
Trial                   : Yes
Count                   : 0
Components              : EXPORT
Host                    : Any

==Software Configuration
$Signed Section         : Yes
Export Configuration    : {
    Supports Export to XML        : Yes
    Supports Export to Text       : Yes
}

==Signature
vpUsQJ+Qo4OS+RQg0vuLW0mXjAj/o6v[trunicated]
```

How can I accomplish this as I'm confused on grouping. I can get it to see the key pairs as thats simple enough, but i dont know how to deal with the splitting using == and the {} pairs?

Comment: Do you really need to use a full parser for that? It looks like your input format is really simple and you can just read it line by line and generate the output as needed.

Comment: Its a type of configuration file for an application I'm writing. "==" is a section split, anything after the version header that isn't in a section will go into a Root section.

Comment: @GregHewgill Its simple at the moment but they might be values that have special things where ill need to use a full parser, yes I *could* do that. like for example i could have sub values in the value using {}'s and it be easier to use a parser then trying to by lines do so.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample configuration file?

Comment: I added the sample. Its for a type of license file. I also adjusted to clarify, I understand Bison to an extent, I'm just confused on how to deal with the groups.

Comment: I don't understand the significance of a `$Key` over a `Key`.

Comment: @user315052 its a special type of value for dealing with the sign verifier or other property based items. Its not that important.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. By the way both answers helped out, but one did expand to deal with Signature and friends which I chose as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your grammar isn't all that simple. But, what I had done was define a token in the lexer to treat `\n==` as the section start symbol (which I called `EQEQ`). So, the grammar rule looked like:

```
section_line:
      EQEQ section_name NEWLINE
    ;
```

And the tokenizing rule looked like:

```
"\n=="           { BEGIN(SEC); return EQEQ; }
```

I used a start condition in order to be able to treat the word `Signature` like a keyword if it was right after the `EQEQ`, and another start condition so that a signature section would just pull in the signature data as a single text blob:

```
<SEC>"Signature" { BEGIN(SIG); return SIGNATURE; }
<SIG>{text}      { return (BEGIN(INITIAL), TEXT); }
```

The grouping rule is easiest defined in a single rule. This is the grammar I used for a property key-value pair:

```
section_property:
      key COLON value NEWLINE
    | key COLON value_block NEWLINE
    ;
```

And then this is the rule I used to define a `value_block`:

```
value_block:
      LBRACE NEWLINE sub_properties RBRACE
    ;
```

And, a `sub_property` looks just like a `section_property`.

Whenever a new section is encountered, your parsing code should remember which section the subsequent value pairs belong to. Likewise, when parsing a sub-property block, the enclosing property key should be saved so that the sub-properties can be appropriately assigned.

One thing that could trip you up in `yacc` like parsers is its bottom up nature. As the leaf elements of a rule are recognized, save the values in the leaf rules, and in your enclosing rule, refer to the saved values. For example, this rule:

```
words:
      WORD { words_add($1); free($1); }
    | WORD { words_add($1); free($1); } words
    ;
```

saves consecutive words into a save buffer representing the word sequence. Then, in an enclosing rule, that save buffer is saved again:

```
key:
      words { words_save_as_key(); }
    ;
```

Where `words_save_as_key` basically dups the saved words buffer, and then resets that buffer for a different sequence that will be saved (likely, the sequence representing the associated value).

Answer (score 3):

Well, whenever trying to decide how to design a flex/bison based parser, the first question is what should be done in flex, and what in bison?

Flex can use use arbitrary regular expressions, and even use states to allow different REs in different contexts, but generally it can only recognize things in isolation -- too much context (more than can be easily provided by a couple of start states) or anything recursive is hard/impossible in flex

Bison on the other hand, handles recursion easily, and can relate tokens in different contexts pretty easily, but the rules are just simple sequences of tokens with no regular expressions and limited (1 token) lookahed.

So in your case, you need to look at the things that are tough to recognize.  The first thing that comes up is `:` -- you use this character both to separate keys from values AND within values.  Can it appear within keys?  If not then you probably just want to handle the first `:` on a line specially (readily done in flex with a start state; a bit harder in bison as it requires by describing all the values that can contain colons)

Next in the 'tricky to recognize' is spacing -- there are spaces within keys and values and also other spaces elsewhere that should probably be ignored.  You can readily manage these in flex.  However, you don't describe any sort of comments that might appear in the input file.  If there are comments, you generally want to recognize (and ignore) them in flex, treating them like ignored space.

Finally there's all the other characters that might appear in a file, but aren't described in your example.  These include all the other punctuation characters -- are they legal within keys or values or not?  The `$` and `==` are described as only appearing at the beginning of a line -- what if they are elsewhere (either after whitespace at the start of a line or within/after a key or value?)

My tendency when given something like this with just a vague, incomplete example is to say that anything else is illegal and should give a decent error message about what is going wrong.  So I'd end up with a flex scanner that looks something like:

```
{KVchar}    [-A-Za-z0-9.+/]      /* legal characters in a key or value */
{WS}        [ \t\r]              /* whitespace -- ignored but allowed in a key or value */

%s COLON                         /* seen a colon on the current line */
%%

":"        { BEGIN(COLON); return ':'; }
\n         { BEGIN(INITIAL); return '\n'; }
<INITIAL>({KVchar}+({WS}+{KVchar}+)*)           {
             yylval.key = strdup(yytext);
             return KEY; }
<COLON>({KVchar}+((:|{WS})+{KVchar}+)*)           {
             /* values may contain colons, but can't start or end with them */
             yylval.key = strdup(yytext);
             return VALUE; }
[${}]      { return *yytext; }
"=="       { return EQEQ; }
{WS}+      ; /* ignore */
.          { fprintf(stderr, "Spurious character '%c' in input\n"); }
```

and the bison file looks something like:

```
%union {
    char *key; /* or value */
}
%token<key>  KEY VALUE
%token       EQEQ
%%

input: header kvpairs sections ;

header: KEY
;

kvpairs: kvpairs kvpair
       | /* empty */
;

kvpair: key ':' value '\n'
      | '\n'
;

key: KEY
   | '$' KEY
;

value: VALUE
     | '{' '\n' kvpairs '}' '\n'
;

sections: sections section | /*empty*/ ;

section: EQEQ KEY '\n' kvpairs ;
```